# How Generates pre-compiled views used by the EF when DbContext is in a DLL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-power-tools

I have a DbContext in an external dll (that I don't own) and I want to generated pre-compiled views for it?

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Pre compiled views for `DbContext` or for models?

Comment: Pre compiled views for DbContext